# Unexpected result: pytest.raises with match parameter when asserting error

Tags: python, regex, pytest

Sanity check please!

I'm trying to understand an unexpected test failure when including the exact message returned from an incorrect function call to the `match` parameter of `pytest.raises()`.

[The docs state](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-raises):

> match – if specified, asserts that the exception matches a text or
>   regex

The sequence of instructions in the repl below pretty much says it all, but for some reason the last test fails.

```py
PS C:\Users\peter_000\OneDrive\git\test> pipenv run python
Loading .env environment variables…
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> import pytest
>>> pytest.__version__
'4.4.1'
>>>
>>> with pytest.raises(TypeError, match='a string'):
...     raise TypeError('a string')  # passes
...
>>> def func():
...     pass
...
>>> func(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
>>>
>>>
>>> with pytest.raises(TypeError, match='func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given'):
...     func(None)  # fails
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python_api.py", line 735, in __exit__
    self.excinfo.match(self.match_expr)
  File "C:\Users\peter_000\.virtualenvs\test-_0Fb_hDQ\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 575, in match
    assert 0, "Pattern '{!s}' not found in '{!s}'".format(regexp, self.value)
AssertionError: Pattern 'func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given' not found in 'func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given'
>>>
```

I thought that perhaps the `'()'` might mean something in regex that would cause the strings not to match but:

```py
>>> with pytest.raises(TypeError, match='func()'):
...     raise TypeError('func()')
```

... passes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Match takes a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) pattern, and some characters like `()` are special. You need to escape them:

```
>>> with pytest.raises(TypeError, match=r'func\(\) takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given'):
... #                                   ^     ^^^^
...     func(None)  # succeeds
>>>
```

The reason why it was failing before is that `()` in a regular expression corresponds to an empty group, and so your pattern would have matched the string `func takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

The reason why `match='func()'` passes is that the particular regex is looking for `func` anywhere in the string: it may be followed or preceded by any text.

Comment: Yes OK, I think I'm with you. If my second test was `with pytest.raises(TypeError, match='func() something'): raise TypeError('func() something')` it causes the same error because the regex pattern `'func() something' ` would only match `'func something'`.

Comment: @SuperShoot: yes, exactly

Comment: Sweet, so given that the api reference uses the terms 'text or regex' and that exception is a built in exception message, not exactly an edge case, would you consider this something that could be posted as a github issue for improvement in the current documentation?

Comment: @SuperShoot: yeah, sure. I've seen many cases of people writing verbatim text in places where a regex is expected (not just in pytest, in many other places), and they have all been source of pain. Having clearer documentation is always good.

Comment: Thanks for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-raises) also mention the possible usage of `re.escape` instead of manually escaping the string. It's possible to write: `with pytest.raises(TypeError, match=re.escape("func() takes 0..."))`

Comment: @Darkonaut that's actually a rewrite of the docs from a PR I submitted after I asked this question! https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/5223/files

Comment: @SuperShoot Great! Already wondered if that could be the case :)

Answer (score 3):

Just do what the error message says and use `re.escape()`:

```
with pytest.raises(TypeError, match=re.escape('func()')):
    raise TypeError('func()')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a method that raises a `ValueError` if too large of an integer is passed into the method. My test method looked like this:

```py
import pytest

def test_func_exceeding_max_value():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="maximum value of (2**32)-1 exceeded"):
        func(2**32)
```

This test is met with the error:

```
re.error: multiple repeat at position 20
```

Position 20 corresponds to this character:

```
maximum value of (2**32)-1 exceeded
                    ^
```

As the error suggests, it is raised from an error in a `regex` expression. What I failed to initially realize is that the `match` parameter in `pytest.raises` is a **regular expression** and not a literal string match. In the [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) documentation, it states:

> You can pass a match keyword parameter to the context-manager [pytest.raises] to test that a regular expression matches on the string representation of an exception...

You need to use two backslashes (`\\`) ***instead of one*** before the special characters `(`, `*`, `)`, etc. This is because when the `match` parameter is sent to the `re.match` method, the backslash itself needs to be escaped so that `re.match` interprets that backslash as a literal character and will then escape the correct character:

```
def test_func_exceeding_max_value():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="maximum value of \\(2\\*\\*32\\)-1 exceeded"):
        func(2**32)
```